# pivot table filter using list on separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I have a pivot table set up exactly how it needs to be, however the ID column is pretty extensive so I am looking to have a macro that easily filters only the IDs that I want for the pivot table. What I would like to do is be able to run a macro which looks at all the IDs I have on sheet2 and goes to my pivot table on sheet1 and only shows those IDs.

I have really been searching to see what other similar topics mentioned. But either those questions and solutions did not apply to what I am trying to do, or they are way over my head that I did not even realize what was occurring in the code. My initial thought was to record a macro where I would select a few IDs to see what the code looked like and then change the IDs on the macro to the cells on sheet2 where my IDs are; that did not work for me so I'm not sure if it was a good idea and bad execution or if I am just way off base right now. But here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub report_filter_macro()
'
' report_filter_macro Macro
' filter only the IDs desired

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("my_pivot").PivotFields("IDs").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("my_pivot").PivotFields("IDs")
        .PivotItems("000022").Visible = False ' does not show ID 000022 in the pivot table
        .PivotItems("000011").Visible = False ' does not show ID 000011 in the pivot table
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("my_pivot").PivotFields("IDs"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True ' allows multiple filters
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: Here's a [post of mine](http://yoursumbuddy.com/filter-pivot-tables-using-source-data-helper-columns/) that explains how to use helper columns in your data that you can then filter the pivot table on. No VBA required. And here's a [VBA alternative](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/) from Jeff Weir.